# Cannot ssh into server except with google dev console ssh

Tags: ssh, debian, gcloud

I cannot ssh from my computer into the server hosted on Google Cloud.

I tried the normal ssh-keygen with user@domain.com and uploading the public key, which worked last time, but this time it didn't. The issue started after I changed the password for the account. After that I could no longer ssh or sftp into the account, although I wasn't disconnected until I disconnected.

I then tried the gcloud ssh user@instance and it ran fine and told me it just hasn't propagated yet.

I added `AllowUsers user` to the server's ssh config file and I restarted ssh on the server, but still the same result

Here's the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

---

Update:

I've been working with Google tech support and this issue is still unresolvable. A file called `authorized_keys` permissions keep getting changed on boot to another user, who I also cannot log in as.

So I change it to:

```
thisUser:www-data 755
```

but on boot it changes it to:

```
otherUser:otherUser 600
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things in order to fix this. You can take advantage of the **metadata** feature in GCE and add a startup script that would automatically change the permissions.

1. From the developers console, go to your **Instance > Metadata** and **add** a pair of **Key/value**

   **key**  : **startup-script**

   **value**: **chmod 755 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys**  OR  **chmod 755 ~/.ssh**
2. after rebooting you should check the **Serial Ouput** option further down that page and see if it ran on startup. it should show you something along these lines :

   startup script found in metadata.

   startupscript: Running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script

Further information can be found [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript#storescriptremotely)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by deleting the existing ssh key under Custom metadata in the VM settings. I then could login on ssh